# Difference between agree and agree to

Tags: verbs

> Mr. Hollande was the French President at the time the deal was
>   **agreed to** in 2015.

But if I construct it the following way:

> Mr. Hollande was the French President at the time the deal was
>   **agreed** in 2015.

I think the second construction is correct. Because ***verb+preposition*** is used for passive forms with some words only like hope.

Comment: You are right. "The deal was agreed in 2015" vs "They agreed ***to*** sign the document in 2015".

Comment: Swap the structure around and it will make more sense - "at the time the French President agreed to the deal". You have to agree *to* or *upon* or *with* something; you can't just "agree something".

Comment: "in 2015" as a phrase can be removed without changing the overall meaning (other than time frame). Then, consider "at the time the deal was agreed to" vs. "at the time the deal was agreed". Considering dictionary examples of [*agree*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/agree) and [*agreed*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/agreed) might help. You probably won't find "agree" standing by itself. Regardless, probably some word like "accepted" or "finalized" might be better

Comment: This exact question was discussed on the English stack exchange some years ago(https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39516/agreed-or-agreed-to#39530) without any consensus being agreed  (or agreed to). For my money in BrE both forms are used and seem equally natural. If one of them seems to conflict with 'rules' then so much the worse for the rules.

Answer (score -1):

In your example

> **agreed**
>   **agreed to**

have the same meaning, that an *agreement* was established.

> For the treaty to be **agreed**, each participant **agreed to** each provision after lengthy discussion. 
>   For the treaty to be **agreed to**, each participant **agreed** after lengthy discussion.